# 10 System LAN latency with ADSL modem as gateway

Tags: networking, lan, latency, adsl-router

Recently I expanded LAN in my office from 3 to 10 computers.

Structure star topology, one ADSL Modem connected to One Switch which is again connected to 10 computers.

Also we have Wifi device Netgear which is connected from switch.

ADSL Modem acts as the DHCP Server, all the system will have default gateway IP (ADSL Modem's IP)

Network latency is now become very high, All the chat severs disconnect often like google talk, skype etc, also internet become very very slow. when all the computer turned on.

We have 4 Mbps Download and 100 Kbps upload Net speed.

Its look like ADSL Modem cannot able to handle all the connections.
I tried to setup a system as default gateway which will connect to modem, not sure how to do this.

Please advice on this.

Comment: QOS and traffic shaping are your friends in such a situation 10 ppl (possibly more with wifi) on 4mbps connection can be rough if they are all using the web at the same time.

Comment: Is it just slow on the internet, or is it slow transferring data from one computer to another?

Comment: @Matt internet is slow, one computer to another looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need some form of traffic shaping or bandwith management to allow the high-priority low latency protocols to get through your now overcrowded internet connections without delay.

A Linux gateway or something similar would do the job, but setting up traffic shaping isn't something a novice user would find particularly easy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems here that not the topology of your network is the culprit, but your DSL speed. 4 mbps download and 100 kbps upload is **very** little for such a relatively high number of simultaneously connected computers. If all of them just browse the internet at the same time, your connection will soon clutter.

4 mbps is not 4 megabytes per second, it's 4 megabits. Bits are 1/8th of a byte, so in fact you only have 500 KBps download and 12,5 KBps upload. Once again, for 10 simultaneously connected computers, this is **very** little. (Not even mentioning the fact that you'll probably never get the full speed your DSL provider promises. You usually get around 80%.)

Even with basic traffic shaping, giving each computer its dedicated and equal share of bandwidth, it would leave very little per computer. (50KBps download/1,25 KBps upload)

The easiest way out: upgrade your subscription to allow higher DSL speeds.

Comment: yea i know that it will come be 512 KBps.
Not all the people browse at same time, main problem is our chat client disconnected from their chat servers. We have a one global IP for all the systems.